# Netlogo: Placing one type of turtle to other type

Tags: netlogo

I am new to NetLogo. I need your help in setting up the turtles. I have two types of breeds: houses and humans. I have set up houses as follow:

```
create-houses 10[
    
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "house"
    set size 3
    
  ]
```

Now I got n-numbers of human agents and I want to set their XY in such a way that human agents should be placed on the top of house agent. Human agents who are on the top of any house agent would assume that this human belongs to that house.
I used the following code to place human agents over the house agent:

```
 create-humans n-numbers
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set xcor [xcor] of min-one-of houses [distance myself]
    set ycor [ycor] of min-one-of houses [distance myself]
]
```

The problem with above approach is that still I got few human agents which are not placed over any house agent. I dont want any agent to be homeless. Is there any way of fixing this issue? In other words I want to distribute (randomly) n-numbers of human agent to 10 house agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two different problems here conceptually.

1. Using space to represent ownership. So once you have the human and the house in the same place, then you will presumably be writing code that means something like "find the house at the same place I am". A much better way of doing that in NetLogo is to use agent variables to assign a house to a person and a person to a house.
2. Moving to a selected house.

This is a complete model that uses the idea of ownership. Each house and human has an attribute that identifies its partner (which solves issue 1). Note that there are other ways to do this, like using links. However, the approach below introduces the least amount of new ideas and is also a good way of understanding turtle attributes, which are an essential concept in NetLogo.

For issue 2, you can use `move-to` when you have a target like a turtle.

```
breed [houses house]
houses-own [my-humans]

breed [humans human]
humans-own [my-house]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-houses 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "house"
    set size 3
    set my-humans nobody
  ]
  create-humans 50
  [ set my-house one-of houses
    move-to my-house
    ask my-house [set my-humans (turtle-set my-humans myself)]
  ]
end
```

As well as the issues I identified, this code uses `with` and `myself`. `with` is straightforward, it simply creates an agentset of turtles that satisfy the condition. `myself` is somewhat confusing - it refers to the turtle doing the asking. So the house is being asked by the turtle to set its "my-human" variable. Whenever you use `myself` in code, it is good practice to check that the code has done what you think it has. In this case, you could open an `inspect` window for a house and a human and make sure that the pair of variables matches.

Edited the code to allow multiple humans at each house. This requires explicit construction of the agentset of humans for each house. It starts with an empty agentset (using the special agent `nobody`) and then takes the union of the previous agentset and the new human (using `turtle-set`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried your code, when I pressed setup button it throws error:  MOVE-To expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.

Comment: I think the problem in my scenario is that I have more human agents (50) and want to assign to 10 house agent. The example you mentioned has 10 human and house agents. That's why its not working. Could you please shed some light on it?

Comment: Okay, I didn't realise that you had multiple humans in a house. I will edit my code.